# Final solution for error with uploading xlsx file via express app to mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel, express, upload, xlsx

I created this very detailed title for every person who will have this same problem like me, because Google doesn`t contain a right solution for it.

I have little app created via express.js framework, using MySQL db and with few dependencies from npm.
The main purpose of this app is to upload xlsx file, read it, and put every single row into MySQL db.
On localhost, i can upload a huge file (10MB for example) with 100k+ records without any problem.
But when i doing it in my hosting my app can only upload a file on server, but can`t handle part with uploading it into MySQL db.
Here is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@zxing/library": "^0.20.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "^1.8.1",
    "mongodb": "^5.8.1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.6.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.2",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
```

Here is my code which is responsible for upload and processing data to DB:

```
/* POST /upload/import-excel-main page. */
router.post('/import-excel-main', uploadFile.single('import-excel-main'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    if (typeof req.file === 'undefined') {

        req.session.info = 'Nie wybrano odpowiedniego pliku!';
        res.redirect('/cos/upload');

    } else {

        importFileToDbMAIN(__basedir + '/public/upload/' + req.file.filename);
        req.session.info = 'Pomyślnie przekonwertowano raport do bazy danych!';
        res.redirect('/cos/upload');


    }
    console.log('log: ' + req.file.filename);
})

function importFileToDbMAIN(exFile) {
    readXlsxFile(exFile).then((rows) => {
        rows.shift()

        connection('DELETE FROM `azt_orders_main` WHERE id > 0', (err) => {
            console.log('Najpierw usunieto Dane!');
            connection('INSERT INTO`azt_orders_main`(`Lp.`, `Magazyn`, `Alert`, `Numer zamówienia`, `Data zamówienia`, `Rodzaj dostawy`, `Data dostawy`, `Czas dostawy`, `Adres dostawy`, `Wartość zamówienia`, `Wartość zaliczki`, `Wartość do pobrania`, `Można wydać`, `Status`, `Numer transportu`, `Komentarz`, `Uwagi`) VALUES ?', [rows], (error, response) => {
                if (error || response) {
                    console.log('Potem poprawnie je wgrano lub nie');

                    connection('UPDATE `azt_orders_main` SET `Adres dostawy` = NULL ', [rows], (error, response) => {
                        if (error || response) {
                            console.log('Usunieto dane wrazliwe (adres dostawy)!');

                            connection('UPDATE `azt_orders_main` SET `Komentarz` = NULL ', [rows], (error, response) => {
                                if (error || response) {
                                    console.log('Usunieto dane wrazliwe! (komentarz)');
                                }
                            })

}
```

And finally here i have my error logs:

```
App 896074 output: log: listazamowien.xlsx
App 896074 output: (node:896074) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid signature: 0x8074b50
App 896074 output:     at /home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/unzipper/lib/parse.js:70:26
App 896074 output:     at tryCatcher (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
App 896074 output:     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
App 896074 output:     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
App 896074 output:     at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
App 896074 output:     at Async._drainQueue (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
App 896074 output:     at Async._drainQueues (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
App 896074 output:     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/p589232/nodevenv/k100pal/10/lib/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
App 896074 output:     at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
App 896074 output:     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
App 896074 output:     at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
App 896074 output: (node:896074) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
App 896074 output: (node:896074) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

To be honest, i didnt try it, but i thought about something buffer? I think that my hosting power is limited (its cheapest one), so it cant process so much data like my localhost env. But i dont have idead how to do that.
I tried to Google that problem: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid signature: 0x8074b50
But i cant find proper solution.